# Issues using Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ntfs, compatibility

Soon I plan on getting some new parts for my computer and when I upgrade I want to use my new SSD for windows 7 and my old one for Ubuntu (I have a lot of very large win software and games). I would like to use Ubuntu as much as possible but I will need to switch back to windows pretty often. I also have a 1TB NTFS HDD for all my personal files and back it up onto another HDD with crash plan.

I have seen some posts where people talk about Ubuntu being very unstable with NTFS but they were old. Is this still the case? I really don't want to have to reformat the 1TB HDD. Will all of these things play nicely? Are there any possible issues with this set up? Everything will be fresh install but I would like to leave the 1TB HDD alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is fine with NTFS and has been for a while now. Yes it used to be unstable but that was quite a few years ago. There is not reason to expect any problems with the setup you describe.

Your `/` and `/home` directories should be on a Linux native file system but having your data on an NTFS partition will not be a problem.